# I am looking for a word to represent a mechanism for uniting similar, yet potentially disparate, operations

Tags: single-word-requests

In my workplace, I am trying to align multiple teams toward a common goal.  Today, we may be doing very similar functions, but with a tilt towards what each unit can directly control, as well as operating what is in each team's own interest.  All told, we may be unintentionally working against each other, diluting the final result.

Consider this example: We have a team with the goal of making the world's best sandwich.  However, each person is accountable for one of the ingredients.  We need each team to consider the other to get the best outcome.

If you were going to create a tool that describes bringing those different perspectives together, and aligns them to the best result, what would you call it?

I've considered:  orchestrator, consolidator, unifier, governor, transmorgifier (a la Calvin and Hobbes), etc.  However, none of those words appeal to me since they don't demonstrate unification across disparate decisions.

Thoughts?

Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: How about ***Harmonizer***?

Comment: Would "coordinator" fit?

Comment: Jim's got it - a Harmonizing principle

Comment: Hi jud, welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Harmogenizer? (from a blend of harmonise and homogenise)

Comment: I’d call it management.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the word: **Synergy**

## Synergy

As defined by Oxford Dictionary: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synergy

> The interaction or cooperation of two or more organizations, substances, or other agents to produce a combined effect greater than the sum of their separate effects.
>
> > Example 1: "You have the right support, cooperation and synergy in the work place to achieve goals."
> >
> > Example 2: "A synergy has developed among the different groups working on this project."

Answer (score 0):

The word **to optimize** means to fashion or engineer something, perhaps involving multiple disparate elements, in such a way that the end-result is closest to the desired goal even if that means that some of the individual elements might have to be maximized and others minimized.

This is not "dilution" (your word) but **optimization**.  And don't think only in terms of computers, where optimization has a narrower meaning and is often used as if it were a synonym of **maximize** which it often isn't.

For example, you might have to bench a star center-forward if his strengths are primarily offensive in nature (he's a play-maker) when your needs at the moment are for a stronger defense. The coach picks an **optimal** starting roster, given the exigencies of the particular opponent.